# How to prove the differential of irrational exponent function?

Tags: real-analysis

In my real analysis text, it defines the irrational exponent as following.

> > Let $x$ be a positive real number and $r$ be an irrational number.
> >
> > (i) $x^r := \sup \{x^t | t \leq r, t \in \mathbb{Q} \}$ for $x \geq 1$.
> >
> > (ii) $x^r := ((x^{-1})^r)^{-1}$ for $0 < x \leq 1$.

I want to prove the following by using this definition.

> > If $a$ is a non-zero irrational number and $f(x) = x^a$, then $f'(x) = ax^{a-1}$.

Help me to prove this.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have defined
$f_t(x) = x^t$
for rational $t$,
you can show that
$f_t'(x)
=t x^{t-1}
$.

Then take the sup of these.

Note that
$f_t'(x)
=t f_{t-1}(x)
$.